# Creating a recursive function from nested loops with dynamic assigns along the way

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, nested-loops

This one is leaving me a bit stumped but in sum, I am working on a graph problem where I 'walking' along a graph (temporally), calculating things and assigning variables along the way. Currently, I have a massive function with nested for-loops, which surely must be convertible to a recursive function. I am just not sure how. Help would be most appreciated.

## MWE

### Setup

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import product

# MWE for SO
D = {"A":(0,1), 'B':(0,1), 'C':(0,1)}
nodes = ['A','B','C']

def assign(assigned, fixed, F):
    for i in nodes:
        if i in fixed:
            assigned[i] = fixed[i]
        else:
            assigned[i] = F[i](assigned)

    return assigned

def func():
    return OrderedDict(
        {
            "A": lambda v: v["A"],
            "B": lambda v: v["B"], 
            "C": lambda v: v["C"],
        }
    )

def func2(past):
    return OrderedDict(
        {
            "A": lambda v: v["A"]^past['A'],
            "B": lambda v: v["B"]^past['B'], 
            "C": lambda v: v["C"]^past['C'],
        }
    )
```

#### First time-step (index)

```
# First time step
fixed1 = {'B':0}
F = func()
for j in product(*[D[i] for i in D.keys()]):
    assigned = dict(zip(D.keys(), j))
    assigned = assign(assigned, fixed1, F)
    # For each j and assigned some logic happens here
```

#### Second time-step (index)

```
# For second time-step, we start nesting
fixed1 = {'B':0}
fixed2 = {'A':1}
F = func()
# t=0
for j in product(*[D[i] for i in D.keys()]):
    assigned = dict(zip(D.keys(), j))
    assigned = assign(assigned, fixed1, F)
    # For each j and assigned some logic happens here

    # t=1
    G = func2(assigned)
    for jj in product(*[D[i] for i in D.keys()]):
        assigned = dict(zip(D.keys(), jj))
        assigned = assign(assigned, fixed2, G)
        # For each jj and assigned some logic happens here
```

#### Third time-step (index)

```
# For second time-step, we start nesting
fixed1 = {'B':0}
fixed2 = {'A':1}
fixed3 = {'A':1}
F = func()
# t=0
for j in product(*[D[i] for i in D.keys()]):
    assigned = dict(zip(D.keys(), j))
    assigned = assign(assigned, fixed1, F)
    # For each j and assigned some logic happens here

    # t=1
    G = func2(assigned)
    for jj in product(*[D[i] for i in D.keys()]):
        assigned = dict(zip(D.keys(), jj))
        assigned = assign(assigned, fixed2, G)
        # For each jj and assigned some logic happens here

        # t=2
        H = func2(assigned)
        for jjj in product(*[D[i] for i in D.keys()]):
            assigned = dict(zip(D.keys(), jjj))
            assigned = assign(assigned, fixed3, H)
            # For each jjj and assigned some logic happens here
```

You can see where this is going (edit for clarity: **for each new time-step I need to add a new nested-loop and this is the part which I want to solve using a recursion**. Worth noting that the `fixed` variables set the other variables to specific values and come from outside this module.

Hence, how do I make this into a recursive function? As you can imagine I am going a lot further than three indices.

Comment: Why would you want to convert your code from iterative to recursive? Recursive is awesome in some programming languages, but not in python. Python is really terrible with recursion. Iterative is almost always better than recursive in python.

Comment: If you're seriously working with graphs, consider using [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html). It's a great python module to handle graphs. Most of the things you will want to do with graphs are "classic" and have been done before, and a convenient and optimised function will be provided by the networkx module. For instance, there are several functions for graph traversal.

Comment: *"Well you can see where this is going."* Actually, I can't. Could you please explain, with words, the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Stef re: recursion sure but I am not going to nest 100 loops with essentially the same code. That's why I want a recursion.

Comment: @Stef I am using networkx for this actually but this has nothing to do with graphs per se which is why I am not mentioning it here. It is nothing to do with classical graph traversal it was just a convenient way for me to explain. The fact that this is on a graph is inconsequential. The loops are the problem.

Comment: @Stef re: where this is going. Sure, so as you can see in the last code-block there are three nested loops. In the one above that code-block, there are two nested loops. For each time step, there is a new nested loop. That is the part I am trying to get rid of with recursion because it's mostly just repetition.

Comment: Note `[D[i] for i in D.keys()]` is the same as `D.values()`, which would be easier to read.

Comment: Could you please explain, with words, what you are trying to do? So far the only thing I understood is that you're trying to walk through an inconsequential graph. Your code is quite complex but doesn't appear to have any output. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It might help if you for instance replaced the `# some logic happens here` comments with actually something happening (such as a call to `print()`), so that your code effectively does something and becomes easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT: New iteration (recursion) based on comment

This calls the fixeds/funcs for all values generated.

```
def do_timesteps(fixeds_funcs, assigned=None):
    (fixed, func), *next_fixeds_funcs = fixeds_funcs
    print(fixed, func, assigned)  # for debugging :)
    F = func(assigned)
    for j in product(*[D[i] for i in D.keys()]):
        assigned = dict(zip(D.keys(), j))
        assigned = assign(assigned, fixed, F)
        if next_fixeds_funcs:
            do_timesteps(next_fixeds_funcs, assigned)


def main():
    fixeds_funcs = [
        ({"B": 0}, func),
        ({"A": 1}, func2),
        ({"A": 1}, func2),
    ]
    do_timesteps(fixeds_funcs)
```

Comment: So this is not quite what I was going for. Notice that `func2` only gets evaluated for _one_ value from assign() using `func`. It needs to be evaluated for _all_ values generated by `assign()` for `func`.

Comment: line 2 can also be written as `(fixed, func), *next_fixeds_funcs = fixeds_funcs`